# Expresso Store Hook store_order_complete_end

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, extension, hook

I am very new to EE2 and using Expresso Store in one of my websites in EE2 and need to use this hook when the order has completed and payment has been made successfully. The code I need to call is this: `ee()->extensions->call('store_order_complete_end', $order);`

What I would like to ask is what do I parse to the $data parameter?

When this hook runs, I need to call a function that generates a coupon code and add this code to the database, but what is the `$order` parameter in this piece of code and where exactly in the project would I call this piece of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find the [EE Extension Development guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html) useful.

Basically, you need to create an extension which handles the `store_order_complete_end` hook. I'm not sure what you mean by the `$data` parameter, but the `$order` parameter is a Store Order model. You can access attributes on it like this:

```
$order->id;
$order->billing_address;
$order->order_total;
```

The attribute names match those found in the [checkout tag](https://exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html).

Comment: Sorry Adrian, I meant $order - Edited this. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to obtain the quantity ordered for each product using the $order array?

Comment: Yes. $order->items[0]->item_qty. It's exactly the same as variable names in the checkout tag.